# Regex : two conditions

Tags: regex

I have a csv file with many lines.

I want to get lines with a `;F;` or a `;A;` but not with `;REPORTING;`.

> 1. 123456;;;;;75;;;;A;18;-83;-7;19;;
> 2. 654321;52;;;;;;;;F;8;-3;7;489;;
> 3. 123456;;;;;;573;;;;1858;-88963;-746;1549;;
> 4. 123456;;523;;;REPORTING;fd3574;;;A;183001;-86583;-457;19211;;

I want to get line 1 and 2 but not line 3 and 4...

I tried :

```
;(?!REPORTING);.*;(F|A);
```

but no success...

Any idea ?

Comment: Depending on the language, a `find` or `in` operation would be cheaper than regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
^(?=.*;[AF];)(?!.*;REPORTING;)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS3vC9/3)**

Comment: Using lookarounds is expensive ! `^(?!.*;REPORTING;).*;[AF];.*` returns the same thing with 100 fewer steps

Comment: @Aaron that's a nice way

Comment: Well actually I don't know where I pulled my 100 steps from. It's still a little more efficient, but just marginally.

Comment: @Aaron finally these all will depend on the input string..:)